# Multiple Timers counting down are not working properly | SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an auction app running. I need several timers counting down in the UI, these timers have different end Dates, and the end seconds can be updated when SignalR receives a new value.

I have implemented running timers in my current solution, but sometimes and suddenly, they start having delays between counting down a second.

**The timers are inside these components called `LotCard` within the `ForEach`**

```
ForEach($lotService.getLotListDto) { $item in
    LotCard(lotCardViewModel: $item.lotCardViewModel,
            lotDto: item,
            fnStartLotConnection: { value in lotService.initSingleLotCard(uID: value)})

}
```

**This is the necessary code within these components:**

```
//MARK: Timer
@State var timeRemaining = 9999
let timerLotCard = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

HStack(spacing: 3){
    Image(systemName: "stopwatch")
    if(lotCardViewModel.showTimer){
        Text("\(timeRemaining.toTimeString())")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .onReceive(timerLotCard){ _ in
                if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                    self.timeRemaining -= 1
                    
                    if(self.timeRemaining <= 0){
                        self.timerLotCard.upstream.connect().cancel()
                    }
                }else{
                    self.timerLotCard.upstream.connect().cancel()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I guess it's a problem with threads and using many timers simultaneously with the same `Instance` but I am not an experienced developer using `SwiftUI`/`Swift`.

This is how my interface looks like:

[image: Interface]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried this: `Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(someTimeInterval), style: .timer)`?

Comment: Decrementing a counter every second is not a good approach. Timers have jitter.  You should calculate the difference between now and the end date. Then you can run your actual timer faster than once per second to give smooth updates. I suggest at least 0.5s

Comment: Timer is not accurate thing, and if there are a lot of them then they really affect each other. I recommend to use one timer, outside, and each LotCard just observer it making own state countdown.

Comment: Read this https://medium.com/@pwilko/how-not-to-create-stopwatch-in-swift-e0b7ff98880f

Comment: I would turn this around.  Instead of using multiple timers, use a single timer and each tick, each "interested party" would then calculate the time remaining based on an anchor time (when their counter started) and when it should end

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer @NoeOnJupiter. I have tried this, but the problem lies in the timer itself, not the output formatting. 

Maybe there is a better way of managing multiple timers.

Comment: Try TimelineView it is likely a better approach. Timers are not accurate.

Comment: Guys, I have implemented **one timer outside**, and every component listens to it. 

I will share my solution soon.

Paulw11 , Asperi , MadProgrammer , thank you, and also thank you to everyone who took the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this approach thanks to the comments in my question.
I hope it works and suits your problems.

First, I created a *Published Timer*, meaning every component will run the same Timer.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class UIService : ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = UIService()

    //MARK: Timer to be used for any interested party
    @Published var generalTimer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

}
```

Finally, I am using that Timer wherever I want to use it. In this case, I use it in every LotCard component.

```
struct LotCard: View {

//MARK: Observable Class
@EnvironmentObject var UISettings: UIService

//MARK: Time for the counting down
@State var timeRemaining = 9999

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        
        Text(timeRemaining.toTimeString())
            .onReceive(UISettings.generalTimer){ _ in
                if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                    self.timeRemaining -= 1
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```